# What does this character mean?

Tags: translation, kanji

I found this necklace and has this as one of the charms. Does anyone know what it translates to?[image: This is the charm.]

Answer (score 4):

That is 「豬」, which is a variant of 「猪」.  We use the latter kanji in Japan now.  Both are read 「いのしし」.

It means a "boar", the animal.

Why make accessories out of a boar?  That is because it is one of the 12 animals of the Chinese/Japanese Zodiac.

Comment: I am いのししどし　^_^ ...not that I believe in astrology.

Comment: Or technically, domesticated "pig", as in Chinese zodiac. Because the accessories are using Taiwanese glyph.